# merge multiple .doc in a single .csv

Tags: java, python, linux, r, csv

I think this is a rather unusual question as I could not find any answer anywhere. I have ~100000 word documents (i.e. clinical reports letters - so they are all free text, with commas, formatting etc) which are all stored in the same folder. I wish to merge them into a single spreadsheet (ideally a .csv), so that each .doc occupies a single row of the .csv.

To complicate the issue, the first 6 characters of each .doc include the ID number of each file (i.e. '123456report.doc' - the 'report' name might also have variable length and characters: i.e '123456John Smith report.doc' or '123457Jack Ryan Rep 01 01 2013.doc'). Originally I had the .doc stored in individual folders which included the ID number (actually it was a sub-folder system and the concatenation of folders names gave the ID number of the .doc which I then managed to add to the file name) - let me know if this is of any use and I can explain in more detail).

So, the final structure I need for the .csv is:

```
ID, Clinical report
123456, clinical text in document 123456report1.doc
123457, clinical text in document 123457report2.doc
123458, clinical text in document 123458report3.doc
...
```

Please note that the ID might repeat in the datasheet (i.e. multiple reports issued for one patient if the patient is examined more than once) and are essential as allow me to cross-reference this ID with other spreadsheets containing other data.

I am not sure if this is something simple (probably not I suppose), but I have no idea of where to start from.  I am not even sure of the best environment to achieve this, so any hint would be greatly appreciated!
Even if this includes acquiring some software that is specifically designed for this type of tasks.

Many thanks,
Marco

Comment: What goes in the second column?  Is it the entire text of the document?

Comment: Yes, I need the whole text in the document in the second column and the ID in the filename in the first. Many thanks!

Comment: I'd write it in VBA, to be honest.  Probably in an Excel template.  Have it list the directory, create a Word object for each file that it finds, then parse out the text and add the right stuff to the spreadsheet.  It's years since I've done this sort of thing, so I can't give you accurate details, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Why would you do this? For full-text search of all documents?

Comment: Many thanks David, I will look into the VBA language (i.e. not sure if someone in my department knows it, as I don't). In the meantime I will see if someone else has any other ideas here in stackoverflow. Cheers!

Comment: Actually, this is rather simple text processing. You can achieve this with any of the many languages you tagged this question with. But what do you actually want? If you expect someone to code it for you, this is the wrong place. Either code it yourself (in any language you are most familiar with) or pay someone to do it.

Comment: Yes Simeon, I need to mine the free-text documents and the software I have to use does not allow to import multiple .doc files at once. Thanks you

Comment: Thank you dirkk, I am really novice (and clueless to some extent - I am a clinician doing a PhD in epidemiology to put things in the right prospect...) to coding. I am really looking for a hint on where to start - I don't mind to pay someone to do this, but I figured I need to have at least an idea to pick the person that speaks the right language for the job at least.

Comment: @MarcoD As I said, you can basically use anything for this as it fairly trivial, so there really is no point in looking into which tool to use: People will use the tool they know best. This is something easily done in under one hour, so I wouldn't waste much time in evaluating languages or rating people for their skills. This is also why this question isn't a good fit for SO: We can't help you with any architectural decision, because there simply is no real architecture.

Comment: Maybe you could use LibreOffice which provides an API to do such things. I don't know the details.

Comment: @ dirkk I am aware I did not provide any code or structure, neither I was looking to snitch a free job, I was just looking for some advice on where to start (i.e. which software to look into). If it can be done using any environment then it's great. The people around me I asked to all said that they had no clue on how to do it (but none of them is a programmer - neither I know one, hence asking here!). Many thanks.

Comment: Obviously, this is the easier half of the job, but to create a csv file using `R` where each row is the document name, just do `setwd("C:/Documents/This Is Where The Doc Files are"); write.csv(dir(), file = "TheFile.csv")` and `TheFile.csv` will be located in the same directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. This is my script and seems to work fine in a subsample of data.
Many thanks to all. Plus I also managed to extract the date from the title too (I left it out the original question to avoid complicating it further - hence the extra few lines of code).

```
files     <- list.files(pattern = "\\.(txt)")
files.ID  <- substr(basename(files), 1, 7)  #SUBSTR() takes the first 7 characters of the name of each file

#TO OBTAIN THE DATE FROM THE FILE TITLE
a <- unlist(strsplit(unlist(files), "[^0-9]+"))  #takes all the numeric sequences from each string in the vector "files" - the first one is a space (all filenames have a space as first character - the second is the ID, the third is the date as DDMMYY ("010513")
b <- a[seq(3, length(a), 3)]  #I take only the every 3rd string which is the sequence of the date.
d <- paste(substr(b,1,2),"/",substr(b,3,4),"/",substr(b,5,6), sep="") #creates the date as dd/mm/yy
files.date <- as.POSIXct(d,format="%d/%m/%Y")

x <- length(files)
j <- 1
reports<-data.frame(matrix(0,x,3))
names(reports)<-c("ID","date","text") #creates data frame with columns ID and Text
for (i in 1:x) {
  texto<-paste(readLines(files[i]),collapse="\n ")
  strip(texto,char.keep=c(".","?","!","-","+","±","~","=","&","%","$","£","@","*","(",")",":",";",">","<"))
  reports$ID[i] <- files.ID[i]
  reports$date[i] <- files.date[i]
  reports$text[i] <- texto
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `R` you could use a loop to process the directory full of files and inside the loop, use `read.transcript` from the package `qdap` to read the files and process them.  `qdap` will also do some of the text analysis for you.  The author of that package is regularly on SO and you may get a fuller answer from him.  But reading up on `qdap` may be all you need to get a solid start.  Questions about making the loop and the details of processing the files would be appropriate for another question (though there are many such questions on SO already and you can probably find what you need by searching SO).  But here is a simple loop structure to give you the idea:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.(docx|DOCX)")
files.noext <- substr(basename(files), 1, nchar(basename(files)) - 4)
out.files <- paste(files.noext, "csv", sep = "")

for (i in 1:length(files)) {
    # process the files here with qdap, accumulating the results into a new
    # structure to be determined; write out as csv
    # you might need two passes, one to unpack the docx, then one to assemble them
    # into a single structure for further analysis
    }
```

Comment: I ended up using readLines (I converted the docs in txt as I figured it was faster that way - a bit of a cheat but didn't take very long in terminal) as the files were .doc and not .docx - correct me if I am wrong, but my understanding is that read.transcript works with docx only. The loop, list.files() and substr() were really helpful hints! Thanks!

Comment: Great.  I would have gone to .txt too and used `readLines` but from your original wording I wasn't sure how far from your initial thoughts you wanted to go.  Are you using `qdap` now?  None of this is my area, but I trust anything from Tyler Rinker.